# MapKit without streets and names

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

How can I hide the streets and the street's name on MapKit? I'm making an application for iOS and I need to load a map without elements like streets, street names, country names or things like that. I would like to have something similar to the standard map of the world with only land and rivers but without streets or texts.

Comment: There's no way to do that with the built-in `MKMapView`. You can hide all streets and their names in the Satellites View but I don't think that's what you want. Try another map API such as [Map Box](https://www.mapbox.com/mobile/) or the good old [Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/ios/)

Comment: @CodeDifferent Oh... Ok

Answer (score 1):

`MKMapView` has a `mapType` property which determines the type of data it displays. If you set it to `.satellite`, it will not overlay street maps and names.

Does that work for your purpose?

Comment: No sorry :( .... I need a map like this : https://www.mapbox.com/help/img/ios/switch/5-pin-mapkit.png without the streets and the names

Comment: That link didn't work for me on my phone. Can you take a screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setMapStyle like this:

```
mapView.getMap().setMapStyle("[" +
                    "{" +
                    "    \"elements\": \"label\"," +
                    "    \"stylers\": {" +
                    "      \"visibility\": \"off\"" +
                    "  }" +
                    "}" +

            "]");
```

[image]